# See when packages were installed / updated using pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, package

I know how to see installed Python packages using pip, just use `pip freeze`. But is there any way to see the date and time when package is installed or updated with pip?

Answer (score 45):

If it's not necessary to differ between updated and installed, you can use the change time of the package file.

Like that for **Python 2 with pip < 10**:

```
import pip, os, time

for package in pip.get_installed_distributions():
     print "%s: %s" % (package, time.ctime(os.path.getctime(package.location)))
```

or like that for slightly newer versions (tested with **Python 3.7 and setuptools 40.8** which bring `pkg_resources`):

```
import pkg_resources, os, time

for package in pkg_resources.working_set:
    print("%s: %s" % (package, time.ctime(os.path.getctime(package.location))))
```

or like that with current (December 2023) versions (tested with **Python 3.11**, using `importlib.metadata` since that can replace the deprecated `pkg_resources`):

```
from importlib.metadata import distributions  
import os, time

for dist in distributions():
    print("%s %s: %s" % (dist.metadata["Name"], dist.version, time.ctime(os.path.getctime(dist._path))))
```

an output will look like `numpy 1.26.2: Sat Dec 30 16:23:13 2023` in all cases.

Btw: Instead of using `pip freeze` you can use `pip list` which is able to provide some more information, like outdated packages via `pip list -o`.

Comment: `import pip` is very interesting.

Comment: The one big downside to looking at `package.location` is that it is just the directory which contains the module directory (e.g. /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), so even if you install one package, this would show all the distributions as having been updated.

Comment: `pip 10` has moved `get_installed_distributions` to a private module: `pip._internal.get_installed_distributions()`

Comment: @skjerns just did that (slighty delayed). ;)

Comment: This no longer works. Nor does using `_internal` Python 3.11.

Comment: Likely a solution to be found digging through this rabbit hole: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56653477/18150609. This is also outdated though, mind you.

Comment: Outdated answer. With Python 3.10: `DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html` and all the times shown are the same - they do not show times of the installation / update of the individual packages.

Comment: The pkg_resources are deprecated in setuptools > 67, but it should work despite the warning. Anyhow, I added another way using importlib.metadata.

Answer (score 17):

Unfortunately, python packaging makes this a bit complicated since there is no consistent place that lists where the package files or module directories are placed.

Here's the best I've come up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Prints when python packages were installed
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import datetime
import os
import pip


if __name__ == "__main__":
    packages = []
    for package in pip.get_installed_distributions():
        package_name_version = str(package)
        try:
            module_dir = next(package._get_metadata('top_level.txt'))
            package_location = os.path.join(package.location, module_dir)
            os.stat(package_location)
        except (StopIteration, OSError):
            try:
                package_location = os.path.join(package.location, package.key)
                os.stat(package_location)
            except:
                package_location = package.location
        modification_time = os.path.getctime(package_location)
        modification_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(modification_time)
        packages.append([
            modification_time,
            package_name_version
        ])
    for modification_time, package_name_version in sorted(packages):
        print("{0} - {1}".format(modification_time,
                                 package_name_version))
```

Comment: This seems to give the most precise results. Also +1 for sorting and nice formatting.

Comment: This is definitely the most useful answer here for viewing when packages were installed/last updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I was recently looking for this too. But although there are many good answers here, the real issue is that since pip is not keeping logs by default, we have to resort to using the file *creation* and *modification* times, known as `ctime` and `mtime`, respectively. (See [MAC-times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_times).) Unfortunately, using this method has two side effects:

1. Different OS's and FS's handles the ctime/mtime differently (if even available)
2. Python installations are using many different directories, and some remain after installations while others are created on the fly when running. Making it hard to know exaclty what files to check the dates on.

However, there is a tool called [pip-date](https://github.com/E3V3A/pip-date) that try to combine a few different methods.

`pip install pip-date`

---

[image]

Comment: The pip-date package is a nice idea, but it does not yet support virtual environments, so it is not useful in production.   See docs for feature list: https://github.com/E3V3A/pip-date   ```Q: What does it not do?

    Does not install packages
    Does not show dependencies
    Does not (yet) show packages in a virtualenv or pipenv envrionment (ToDo)
    Does not check package consistency
    Does not show the very first time you installed a package, if it has been updated since.
    (Althought there are left-over artifacts that may show otherwise, we don't look for these.)```

Comment: [poetry](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry) is also a nice alternative package manager, but I still don't see any dates there.

Comment: Also, I believe that if you're using `pip-date` in Windows, the API for file access times (i.e. the *cTime* & *mTime* equivalents) has changed in the last few years, so I am not sure that the last version has been fixed for this.

Comment: For virtual environments, you don't need a package manager, but [venvlink](https://github.com/fohrloop/venvlink).

Answer (score 12):

**Solution 1 : packages.date.py :**

```
import os
import time
from pip._internal.utils.misc import get_installed_distributions

for package in get_installed_distributions():
     print (package, time.ctime(os.path.getctime(package.location)))
```

**Solution 2 : packages.alt.date.py :**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Prints when python packages were installed
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import datetime
from pip._internal.utils.misc import get_installed_distributions
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    packages = []
    for package in get_installed_distributions():
        package_name_version = str(package)
        try:
            module_dir = next(package._get_metadata('top_level.txt'))
            package_location = os.path.join(package.location, module_dir)
            os.stat(package_location)
        except (StopIteration, OSError):
            try:
                package_location = os.path.join(package.location, package.key)
                os.stat(package_location)
            except:
                package_location = package.location
        modification_time = os.path.getctime(package_location)
        modification_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(modification_time)
        packages.append([
            modification_time,
            package_name_version
        ])
    for modification_time, package_name_version in sorted(packages):
        print("{0} - {1}".format(modification_time,
                                 package_name_version))
```

**Solution 1 & 2 compatibility :**

- updated solution for pip v10.x
- python v2, v2.7, v3, v3.5, v3.7

Comment: Solution 1 worked great for Python 3.8.10

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`--log`](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/pip.html#cmdoption--log) option:

```
--log <path>   Path to a verbose appending log. This log is inactive by default.
```

E.g:

```
$ pip install --log ~/.pip/pip.append.log gunicorn
```

Or you can set it in your `pip.conf` to be enabled by default:

```
[global]
log = <path>
```

Then all the `pip` operations will be logged verbosely into the specified file along with a log separator and timestamp, e.g.:

```
$ pip install --log ~/.pip/pip.append.log gunicorn
$ pip install  --log ~/.pip/pip.append.log --upgrade gunicorn
```

logs the following to ~/.pip/pip.append.log:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/pip run on Mon Jul 14 14:35:36 2014
Downloading/unpacking gunicorn
...
Successfully installed gunicorn
Cleaning up...
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/pip run on Mon Jul 14 14:35:57 2014
Getting page https://pypi.python.org/simple/gunicorn/
URLs to search for versions for gunicorn in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages:
* https://pypi.python.org/simple/gunicorn/
...
Requirement already up-to-date: gunicorn in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

You could parse out what you need from this log. While not the nicest it's a standard `pip` facility.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know all `pip` options but for one module you can get list of its files
and then you can check its dates using python or bash.

For example list of files in `requests` module

```
pip show --files requests
```

result:

```
Name: requests
Version: 2.2.1
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: 
Files:
  ../requests/hooks.py
  ../requests/status_codes.py
  ../requests/auth.py
  ../requests/models.py

etc.
```

**BTW:** you can use `--help` to see more options for some functions

```
pip --help
pip list --help
pip show --help
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

`pip freeze` gives you all the installed packages. Assuming you know the folder:

`time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file))`

should give you the creation time of a file, i.e. date of when the package has been installed or updated.