# How to see when all packages were installed with pip?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I'd like to be able to see when every package was installed with pip.  I've checked out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24736316/3238611), but the top answer makes no differentiation between installed and updated packages.

Comment: You should check out the answer on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6600878/find-all-packages-installed-with-easy-install-pip

Comment: That's not really what I'm looking for - pip freeze/list do not show when something was installed, only the version number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get date and time of installation for packages installed via pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559214/get-date-and-time-of-installation-for-packages-installed-via-pip)

Comment: The accepted answer there only shows when something was last updated.  I am interested in learning when it was originally installed.

Answer (score 0):

use command pip freeze 
It Outputs installed packages in requirements format. Packages are listed in a case-insensitive sorted order. Refer https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/