# pip/conda find stale packages (that haven't been updated in 2+ years)

Tags: pip, conda

Is there an easy way in `pip` or `conda` to create a list of all stale packages in the current virtual environment?

By "stale package" I mean the following two criteria are met:

1. There are no updates available.
2. The last release happened >2 years ago.

I want to use this to weed out packages from my large default enviroment of projects that are no longer maintained.

Answer (score 1):

On the Pip-side of things, the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559214/get-date-and-time-of-installation-for-packages-installed-via-pip) should cover your needs.

On the Conda side, there isn't any CLI command that provides such functionality, but one can look at the timestamps on the JSON files in the `conda-meta/` folder of the environment. Those get updated whenever a package is installed.

At first pass, one could list the files sorted by oldest to newest:

```
## environment name
env_name="foo"

## resolve its location
env_path=$(conda run -n ${env_name} echo $\{CONDA_PREFIX\})

## list files in its `conda-meta` folder
ls -lthr ${env_path}/conda-meta
```

Note that the `history` and `pinned` files are special and do not correspond to packages.

Otherwise, one could use `find` to [list all files older than a given date](https://serverfault.com/q/122824).

Comment: Oh, there is a misunderstanding. I am not interested in when I updated the file on my computer, I am interested in when the packages were released in the pypi/conda repository. Basically, from time to time I want to compile a list of packages to consider dropping from my default environment because the projects are not maintained anymore.

Comment: @Hyperplane oops, sorry about that! I’m still going to leave this here, just in case someone comes across this question looking for this particular answer.