# How to find history of recently upgraded python packages

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pip

I have recently upgraded several packages, like pandas, sklearn, in my python environment, via pip, and am now getting very different results.
How can I retrieve a history of recent upgraded packages so I can try to track down why I am seeing a huge difference in accuracy in my model?

I have tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736316/see-when-packages-were-installed-updated-using-pip):

```
import pip, os, time

for package in pip.get_installed_distributions():
    print ("%s: %s" % (package, time.ctime(os.path.getctime(package.location))))
```

But this seems to be giving me only the installed time, not the update time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [See when packages were installed / updated using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736316/see-when-packages-were-installed-updated-using-pip)