# default python packages after first installation

Tags: python, libraries

How can I understand which libraries are installed by default by python after first installation? there is a default list packages of python 3.10?

How can I separate libraries that I have installed after the first default python installation? How can i manage them using pip visualizing also the installation date?

thank you

Comment: Look at the documentation of the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). Those libraries are installed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I believe this is a valid question and problem for Python3 users. The answer has been sought several hundreds of times. I suggest it be answered with Pareto, 80/20 concept. Stack is becoming too stuffy anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find the list of standard library packages installed: [Python Libraries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html).

Furthermore I suggest you to use virtualenv in order to separate the future packages in different projects.

In order to get installation date and hour

```
import pkg_resources, os, time

for package in pkg_resources.working_set:
   print("%s: %s" % (package, time.ctime(os.path.getctime(package.location))))
```

Source code: [See when packages were installed / updated using pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24736316/see-when-packages-were-installed-updated-using-pip/24736563#24736563)